# What are all the bhawana (meditation) methods in Buddhism?

Tags: theravada, vipassana, meditation-samatha

There are two types of meditations described as "Samatha" and "Vipassana"
I have heard that there are several types of samatha bhawana (40 kamatahan). Can you please elaborate this based on Theravada Buddhism

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2014/methods-for-reaching-jhana/2039#2039

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As answered [here](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/2039/18), the forty samatha meditation objects are:

**1-10: The Kasinas**

*These all lead to the four jhānas; they are practised by creating a disk and focusing on it, while repeating, e.g., "earth, earth..."*

1. Earth

2. Water

3. Fire

4. Air

5. Blue

6. Yellow

7. Red

8. White

9. Light

10. Space

**11-20: Foulness**

*These lead to the first jhāna; they are practised by contemplating a corpse in various states of decay*

11. Bloated

12. Livid

13. Festering

14. Cut Up

15. The Gnawed

16. Scattered

17. Hacked and Scattered

18. Bleeding

19. Worm-infested

20. a Skeleton

**21-30: Recollections**

*Body and Breathing bring jhāna (body only brings the first jhāna, breath brings all four); the other eight bring only access concentration; they are cultivated by reflecting on the object, e.g. "Buddha, Buddha"*

21. Buddha

22. Dhamma

23. Sangha

24. Morality

25. Generosity

26. Angels

27. Death

28. Body

29. Breathing

30. Peace

**31-34: The Divine Abidings**

*The first three bring about the first three jhānas; the fourth brings about the fourth jhāna; they are cultivated by taking beings as an object, e.g. "May all beings be happy"*

31. Love 

32. Compassion

33. Joy 

34. Equanimity

**35-38: The Immaterial States**

*These bring about the fourth jhāna; they are cultivated by using the fourth jhāna as a base, then expanding and refining the object*

35. Limitless Space

36. Limitless Consciousness

37. Nothingness

38. Neither Perception Nor Non-perception

**39. Perception of Repulsiveness in Nutriment**

*This brings about only access concentration; it is practiced by reflecting on food as one collects and eats it.*

**40. Defining of The Elements**

*This brings about only access concentration; it is practiced by breaking the body up into the four elements.*

All forty meditation subjects are described and taught in detail in the Visuddhimagga; highly recommended for those interested.