# Jhana Explaination

Tags: jhana, buddha, metta, tipitaka

Namo Buddhaya!

Can someone please SIMPLY explain the EIGHT Jhanas, specifically:

> 1) What are Jhanas meant to do & why would one want to achieve them?
>
> 2) How does one specifically achieve them (instructions please)?
>
> 3) What happens in each individual Jhana, from the first to the
>   eighth?
>
> 4) How can I explain the Jhanas to a newcomer of the Dhamma?

**Please use scripture to back up your answers, but don't make your whole answer scripture...**

Metta!

Comment: where is a duplicate?

Comment: I think this was a duplicate or very nearly a duplicate, of a previous topic (i.e. [Please describe all the Jhanas in everyday languague](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/34245/254)). If this question isn't the same as the previous/existing topic, please clarify how this question is different.

Comment: the question is very extensive while other questions are very specific to only certain matters

Comment: i answered here: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2014/methods-for-reaching-jhana?rq=1 because Yuttadhammo answered here.

Comment: @Dhammadhatu The banner at the top which says, "This question already has an answer here" -- do you see that has an "edit" link which you can click, to add to the list of questions of which this is a duplicate? I edited this list to add links to the two other topics which you edited just now, but perhaps you too could edit the list if you want to.

Comment: Thanks. I will sort out my answers later. I must go now

Comment: `1) What are Jhanas meant to do & why would one want to achieve them?` and `3) What happens in each individual Jhana, from the first to the eighth?` are not asked elsewhere. `2) How does one specifically achieve them (instructions please)?` is answered in [Methods for reaching Jhana](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2014/methods-for-reaching-jhana) and `4) How can I explain the Jhanas to a newcomer of the Dhamma` is explained in [Describe all the Jhanas in everyday language](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/34245/please-describe-all-the-jhanas-in-everyday-languague)

Comment: I posted an answer to this question here: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/35158/295

Comment: @SumindaSirinathS.Dharmasena Well let's see if Dhamma4All edits it somehow. At the moment I read it as, "A simple explanation of what and why and how for all jhanas and each jhana, with references and your own explanation", which is very broad -- i.e. a long answer to do well, maybe a full answer isn't possible, except perhaps by referencing a good book which could answer the question. But IMO anything which could be put in an answer to this question would also fit as an answer to [Describe all the Jhanas in everyday language](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/34245/254).

Comment: `1) What are Jhanas meant to do & why would one want to achieve them?` will remain largely unaddressed if it put there. I believe this question deserves own answer as putting the answer under another answer makes it out of place. Any way pingback if the question is opened. For the time being, I put the answers under the other question.